# Categories in Magento 2 won't load - Some do some don't even - Creating new ones won't load either

Tags: php, jquery, json, magento, magento2

(magento 2.2) anyone else feel magento is super buggy and unpredictable? anyway, my biggest problem is this:

i have several categories that when you click on the product the site loads just fine. but there are other categories for no reason whatsoever just do not load (on front end). if i create a new category with different name and put 0 products in it, it loads. the moment i add 1 product, any product to its category or sub categories, any categories in the parent and child categories do not load.

for example: 
Default Category
     - Clothing
           - Shirt
as soon as i add a product to clothing and/or shirt, both click on clothing and shirt on the front end stop loading.

i get a blank page and the console shows this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 153
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getNodeData (scripts.js:87)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at scripts.js:117
at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:64)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
```

i have tried cache flush, cache clean, reindexing, putting the site in developer mode and then recompiling to production mode. the category is a sub category of the Default Category where everything else is. it does not matter if i create other sub categories or not, as soon a product is added to a new category it will not load on the front end. nothing about my site is super complex.

Answer (score 0):

omg - i figured it out.

apparently you cannot use " in a sku. quotes in a sku for whatever reason creates the problem above. so for any pour soul reading, remove the quotes in your sku.

why, if this is the case, would it even allow you to save a product with " in the sku!

ok - it gets stranger. apparently it can handle quotes IF the quotes come from a product configuration. i have some products with quotes in the sku but those quotes are from a drop down field in product configurations. VERY STRANGE.